# Timestamp comparison in spark-scala dataframe

Tags: scala, timestamp, apache-spark-sql

I have a field in spark dataframe of type string, and it's value is in format `2019-07-08 00:00`. I have to perform a condition on the field like

```
df.filter(myfield > 2019-07-08 00:00)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard comparison operators for `String` should work, given your date format is in British military form:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "2019-07-06 16:00"),
  (2, "2019-07-08 09:00"),
  (3, "2019-07-11 06:30")
).toDF("id", "date")

df.filter(col("date") > "2019-07-08 00:00").show
// +---+----------------+
// | id|            date|
// +---+----------------+
// |  2|2019-07-08 09:00|
// |  3|2019-07-11 06:30|
// +---+----------------+
```